# Automapping only under specific namespace

Tags: c#, automapper, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I don't know why but with this settings automap tries to map BaseClass too, how can I fix this?

> The entity 'BaseClass`1' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method
>   to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id).

```
    _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()                      
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(ConnectionString).ShowSql())
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Foo.E.MenuItem>()
    .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Foo")
    .Setup(cfg => { cfg.FindIdentity = member => member.Name == member.DeclaringType.Name + "Id"; }))
    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

**Namespace X**

```
public partial class BaseClass<T>
{
    //somecode
}
```

**Namespace Foo**

```
public class MenuItem : BaseClass<MenuItem>
{
    public virtual int MenuItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual MenuItem Parent { get; set; }

    public MenuItem()
    {
        Children = new List<MenuItem>();
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, do not you feel like the one who can help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413401/managing-inheritance-using-fluent-nhibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IgnoreBase solved my problem.

```
 .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add( AutoMap.AssemblyOf<T>()
 .IgnoreBase(typeof(BaseClass<>))
```